# Why is it a single fragment is taking the whole screen in an activity with other views that usesconstraint layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

there are two framelayouts in my main activity which will be replaced by two fragments during run time. I am using constraint layout to align them .
One particular fragment that occupies a framelayout with id **recentsfragment** is replacing the whole screen and giving no place to other framelayout .

when i individually display the framelayouts with their fragments,the view is exactly as expected .

**activity_main.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout


  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/recentsfragment"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="325dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.618"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"></FrameLayout>

<view
    android:id="@+id/view"
    class="android.widget.Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-51dp" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/allnotesfragment"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="327dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></FrameLayout>
```

I have tried different alignments for them with no luck. I want to use constraint layout in particular.
any help is appreciated .Thank you.

Comment: try to change both `FrameLayout` tags to match constraints , `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_height="0dp"`

Comment: Thank you for the response but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not really because of the layouts but because in one of the fragments above I used data binding inappropriately and that occupied the whole screen of the app leaving no space for other fragment . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Check your constraint. Top and bottom constraint you are giving wrong.
>   Try below code.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/recentsfragmentTop"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <view
            android:id="@+id/view"
            class="android.widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/allnotesfragmentBottom"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Great answer, you got my upvote. Check my answer below, I believe that it is more simple. In addition, it can change the height (responsive to all screen sizes) of both of the frame layouts within a few seconds. Maybe you can learn something new form my answer. And every time you learn something new you become a better developer

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your both FrameLayout as `0dp` like `android:layout_height="0dp"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"` for both of your `FrameLayouts`and achieve 2 views that take half of the screen size without even needing oyur `view` in the xml - like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/recentsfragmentTop"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/allnotesfragmentBottom"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background" />



<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/allnotesfragmentBottom"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recentsfragmentTop"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**It will look like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/allnotesfragment"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="327dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></FrameLayout>

<view
    android:id="@+id/view"
    class="android.widget.Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/recentsfragment"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/allnotesfragment" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/recentsfragment"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="325dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view"></FrameLayout>
```

Comment: it doesn't work too. The other fragment inflates the whole screen

Comment: can you consider using another Layout such as LinearLayout, if yes, I have an XML for you to try.

Comment: I added linear layout and when I try to initialise second fragment from main activity ,I get an error " no view found for id  ....for fragment " .

Comment: okay ,here it is   **@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecentsFragment recentsFragment=new RecentsFragment();
        BlankFragment blankFragment=new BlankFragment();
      fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.recentsfragment,recentsFragment).commit();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.allnotesfragment,blankFragment).commit();**

Answer (score 0):

try this Linear Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/recentsfragment"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="325dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" >

</FrameLayout>

<view
    android:id="@+id/view"
    class="android.widget.Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/allnotesfragment"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="327dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" >

</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

add these three methods to your Activity class:

```
public int getWidth(){
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    return width;
}

public int getHeight(){
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    return height;
}

public void addFragment(){

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    RecentsFragment recentsFragment = new RecentsFragment(); 
    BlankFragment blankFragment = new BlankFragment(); 

   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.recentsfragment, recentsFragment).commit();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.allnotesfragment, blankFragment).commit();

}
```

and also this code in the onCreate:

```
    recentFragment = findViewById(R.id.recentsfragment);
    allNotesFragment = findViewById(R.id.allnotesfragment);

    recentFragment.requestLayout();
    allNotesFragment.requestLayout();

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (getHeight()/2)-10);
    recentFragment.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    allNotesFragment.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    addFragment();
```

Comment: That did not solve the issue .now the new error shows up .**" No view found for id 0x7f070044 (com.example.diary:id/allnotesfragment) for fragment BlankFragment"**

Comment: ok try editing your question and then attach the screenshot of the error or include the code as it is in the question because both the two methods works fine here i think the problem is somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Inside constraint layout, I just provided android:layout_height="0dp". It works effectively!